# How to add commit information to file?

Tags: mercurial

How can I automatically add information like below to certain files after committing?

`Last commit by Max, 30.02.2013, revision 123, branch xy`

(By the way, it's an `index.html`-file and and it would be nice to use `<--` comments `-->`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) added and configured (i.e some missing by default keyword's definitions added and keywords *properly* added to files)

Comment: Pay attention to the suggestions on that page that there are other, better, ways of doing this. The biggest issue is that you need everyone to have this extension in place otherwise their files aren't keyword expanded.